# Access the original object data path where a property/object is stored in?

Tags: python, scripting, grease-pencil, properties

I have a kind of theoric question.

I've registered a `PropertyGroup` Class to the `GreasePencil` class/type, lets call it `Property_A`.

At the same time, this Property_A has Collection Property with different elements.

(So, I have an structure like):

```
a_grease_pencil_object.property_a.collection
```

**My question is**:

Having an element/instance of that collection, **is it possible to know/get the original Grease Pencil where it is stored?**

Some kind of tracing back where it belongs?

I'm new and Im not sure how bl_rna works, but maybe some kind of just getting the name of the Grease Pencil where the property is stored, so I can get it via `bpy.data.grease_pencils[name]`?

(I need this since for some methods, I accesed the Grease Pencil by the active Grease Pencil. But now I have to loop over all the grease pencils (using `bpy.data.grease_pencils`  to change different things, and since those methods use the active GP, they dont work. So Im looking to replace that code for the thing Im asking).

Edit:
**Reformulating my question (maybe in a simpler way), I want to kind of get the data path of a property**

So if I have `element_zero = a_grease_pencil_object.property_a.collection[0]`

somekind of method that could make something like:

```
element_zero.get_data_path()
```

And I get kind of:

```
bpy.data.grease_pencils["GPencil.011"].property_a.collection
```

So I know that I could get the name of the Grease Pencil object where it is from.

Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can very simply use `repr(prop)`, or in your case `repr(element_zero)`. This will return a string with the full data path from `bpy`.

From the [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) documentation :

> Return a string containing a printable representation of an object.
> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that
> would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval();
> otherwise, the representation is a string enclosed in angle brackets
> that contains the name of the type of the object together with
> additional information often including the name and address of the
> object. A class can control what this function returns for its
> instances by defining a **repr**() method. If sys.displayhook() is not
> accessible, this function will raise RuntimeError.

If you want access to the base ID object (ie the grease pencil object) holding the property, you can use `prop.id_data`. See the docs for [bpy.types.Struct.id_data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.id_data).

Comment: Both options does exactly what I wanted! And I can't believe I wasn't aware of id_data until you pointed it. Thank you so much for the help friend, much appreciated!

Comment: @Ommadawn hehe always a pleasure to answer well documented and thought out questions. I still discover new things and tricks every day ! Cheers