# Accessing the ("Parent") PropertyGroup that stores another PropertyGroup/PointerProperty from the "child"?

Tags: python, properties

Here is my question:

I have a `CollectionProperty` that contains `PropertyGroups` (lets call them "*ObjectA*" Class).

This *ObjectA* Class have in its properties a variable of type `PointerProperty` that stores a refference to a `PropertyGroup` (lets call it "*ObjectB*").

(So basically):
Collection -> Has "*ObjectA*" elements -> ObjectA has a reference/variable of an *ObjectB*.

**I need to access from *ObjectB*, the *ObjectA* that stores them.**

(I made a [kinda similar question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299625/access-the-original-object-data-path-where-a-property-object-is-stored-in), and user Gorgious kindly pointed me that I could use `repr()` to get the data path (I could manipulate it (to basically get rid of the last `.object_b` in my data path, and I guess that I could use `eval()` to execute that code. But I feel is kinda hacky, and maybe there is a more propper/"elegant" way that I'm missing (Like that self.id_data in that question))

Thank you so much for the help, much appreciated!

---

Edit: to add how Im making at the moment in case is helpful for someone else (despite Im not sure if there is a better way):

```
    # (In ObjectB.py)
    ...
    path = repr(self).rsplit(".", 1)[0]
    objectA = eval(path)
```

Comment: Hello ! I don't think there is a built-in way less hacky than the solution you found. You also can't add a PointerProperty to the child class pointing to its parent because that would cause a inheritance loop. However I think this limitation is intentional, in programming usually children (or subclasses) don't need nor want to be aware of who their parent is. this goes back to the SOLID principles of programming where constructs should only do one thing and interact as little as possible with other constructs.

Comment: Parents can query things inside their children, but children shouldn't be able to query their parents. Maybe your problem could be solved by a different architecture ? Keep in mind this is only a principle and your workflow might necessitate such a setup, but you'll have to rely on hacky workarounds I'm afraid. There is also this thread that might help you a bit although it seems like it's basically the same solution as you propose. https://blenderartists.org/t/getting-property-groups-parent-group/599301

Comment: Thank you so much Gorgious, much appreciated as always friend! 
Yeah, you are totally right, it kinda "smelled" like a bad practice. (Is meant to be a subclass to declutter the code related a specific functionality from the "parent". I thought about that approach instead of constantly passing the object as an argument (maybe would be the best)).
Thank you again for the help mate!